# How do I extract numbers from a string in JavaScript without using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, extract

For example, I have a string "asdf123d6lkj006m90" and I need the following result [123, 6, 0, 0, 6, 90].
I tried:

```
let str = "asdf123d6lkj006m90"
let func = function(inputString){
    let outputArray = []
    let currentNumber = ""
    for(let element of inputString){
        if(Number(element)||element == 0){
            outputArray.push(Number(element))
        }
    }
    return(outputArray)
}
console.log(func(str))
```

But it returns [ 1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0, 6, 9, 0 ]
How do I receive the correct numbers?

Comment: That's because you're looking at 1 character at a time. I doesn't seem like you have an objective goal though. The `0`s part is confusing, and that's not what a regex would return either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at each character at a time, when you should be checking the next few as well.

```js
const str = "asdf123d6lkj006m90";
console.log(numbers(str));

function numbers(str) {
  const nums = []; // create an array with the numbers
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // in your example you want preceding 0s to be their own number
    if(str[i] == 0) {
      nums.push(0);
      continue;
    }
    
    let current = ""; // add to our string
    while(!isNaN(str[i])) {
      // as long as the character can be converted to a number
      current += str[i++];
    }
    // if there were any numbers added
    if(current.length)
      nums.push(+current);
  }
  return nums;
}
```

And note, while this looks like O(n^2) because of the nested loop, it's actually still linear because the loops are traversing the same array and one picks up where the other left off.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just starting to learn JS and it's a bit difficult:) I appreciate your help

Comment: @Enedwaith no problem. I hope it helped you. (By the way, if it solved your problem, would you mind selecting it as such? Thanks!)